# How do I get MOQ of bundle products?

Tags: magento2, bundled-product, quantity

How do I get MOQ of the bundle products? since Bundle product itself doesn't need to set MOQ itself, it depends on the children products. But how do I determine which children MOQ that the bundle is using?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using this to get the MOQ in session

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php /** @var $block Magento\Bundle\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle */ ?>
<?php
$product = $block->getProduct();
$helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$stripSelection = $product->getConfigureMode() ? true : false;
$options = $block->decorateArray($block->getOptions($stripSelection));
$validationRules = [
    'required-number' => true,
    'validate-item-quantity' => [
        'minAllowed' => $product->getStockData()['min_allowed'] ?: 1,
        'maxAllowed' => $product->getStockData()['max_allowed'] ?: 1000000,
        'qtyIncrements' => $product->getStockData()['qty_increments'] ?: 1,
    ],
    'validate-item-blank-quantity' => [
        'minAllowed' => (int)$product->getMinBlankQtyAllowedInCart() ?: 1,
        'maxAllowed' => $product->getStockData()['max_allowed'] ?: 1000000,
        'qtyIncrements' => (int)$product->getBlankQtyIncrements() ?: 1,
    ]
];


$_SESSION['validationRules'] = (int)$product->getMinBlankQtyAllowedInCart();

?>
```